# Win32_Service is missing

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, wmi, wmi-service

I have C# code that tries to load some property from WMI object - Win32_Service. But it returns to me 'System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid class ' error.

My simplified code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string serviceName = "AppFabricEventCollectionService";
    string propertyName = "StartName";
    var obj = GetProperty(serviceName, propertyName);
}

private static string GetProperty(string serviceName, string propertyName)
{
    using (ManagementObject obj2 = GetWindowsServiceManagementObject(serviceName))
    {
        return (obj2.GetPropertyValue(propertyName) as string);
    }
}
public static ManagementObject GetWindowsServiceManagementObject(string serviceName)
{
    return new ManagementObject(string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName));
}
```

Also I've tried to load list of WMI objects by PowerShell command -

Get-WmiObject -List | Select Name

It returns 91 objects, but it misses Win32_Service object.  I googled how to reinstall it, but didn't found it. Is there a way to reinstall it somehow?

Thank you

**Update 1:**
Output for Powershell command:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject Win32_Service
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "Win32_Service"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject Win32_Service
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
   ommands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: In Powershell, does `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |  Select Name` work?

Comment: nope. it doesn't work. I added output into Update 1

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it. OS is Windows 7 x64 enterprise SP1

Answer (score 4):

Try reregistering the base classes (admin commandline, of course...)

```
mofcomp %windir%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.mof
```

Comment: The only one place where I found cimwin32.mof is C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-w..ovider-cimwin32-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_2dd0f6a01caf55c6 folder. When I tried to reregister it, it returned such error - http://justpaste.it/4pi5

Answer (score 1):

See the section "I’m getting an 0x80041010 (“Invalid Class”) error" [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406382.aspx). You might find something useful, in particular the use of [Scriptomatic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd939957.aspx) and [Wbemtest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692770.aspx).

Comment: I've tried wbemtest. But when I clicked Connect, it displayed error message: "Number: 0x80040154
Facility: Interface
Description: Class not registered"